# Reg. CSLA 1.1 Framework in .NET 4.5.2

Tags: .net, migrate, csla, .net-4.5.2

Nice day!!

I am writing this to you in the context where we migrate existing ASP.NET 1.1 to .NET 4.5.2, inline to that we identified CSLA 1.1 is being used for Business objects in ASP.NET 1.1 application. We did migrated the entire application to .NET 4.5.2 now without any issues, but just want to clarify/confirm from you whether can we retain existing CSLA 1.1 as is (or) do we need to upgrade CSLA 1.1 to the latest version which supports .NET 4.5.2?

Also, if we can retain existing CSLA 1.1 as it is, what could be the possible impact in .NET 4.5.2?

It would be great, if you could shed some lights on this please.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

First think of the reason why you upgraded the .net framework to a new version. I geuss for support and maybe to use soms new features. For clsa the same reasons apply. 1.1. Is like the stone age and you have no support. Upgrading without using/redesign should not so be hard. However I would recommend making yourself familiar with the new features and see if they can be usefull for you. On how much effort it is, no one can tell you without seeing you code.